# Share a Azure Cloud Service instance with another developer

Tags: azure

I have setup a cloud service instance on Azure with my Windows Live ID.

Is there a way I can share this instance to another developer so he can deploy using his own Azure account without having my Windows Live username/password?

Cheers,
Oscar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes- you should be able to assign the other developer as a co-admin
Look at the Settings entry in the left hand menu and then the Administrators tab at the top